# Draw Graphics on Windows Ce 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, compact-framework

My project is getting data from strip polishing (marble) machine.
Machine have Twincat and Windows Ce device.
I am programming Windows CE. I show stone in the machine and bridge in MyView form

Machine have 55 sensors and its resolution x:4 y:1 cm.
Machine send me a pulse every 1 cm.
When I get pulse read sensors.And DrawGraphics.
My idea :
I have treadmill picture like this

every pulse I am cutting (1 ,220) image from left side
and Adding new sensor values to right side of picture  so picturebox image is sliding there is no problem When
pulse is slow.if pulse is fast my program couldnt draw image.How can I be fastest ?

```
Bitmap TasP = new Bitmap(1099, 220);
Bitmap Tas
{
    get
    {    
        int tasy = 0;
        Bitmap temptas = new Bitmap(1099,220);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(temptas))
        {
            g.DrawImage(TasP, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1098, 220), new Rectangle(1, 0, 1098, 220),GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            g.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.sbant2, new Rectangle(1098, 0, 1, 220), new    Rectangle(20, 0, 1, 220), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            var tempsensor = TaramaSensor;
            foreach (bool sensor in tempsensor)
            {
                if (sensor)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.tas, 1098, tasy, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 4), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
                tasy = tasy + 4;
            }
        }
        TasP = temptas;
        picturebox1.Image=temptas;
        return TasP;
    }
    set
    {
        TasP = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How fast the pulse is? In win CE the limitation usually is the device itself.

Comment: @mbm Max 120 miliseconds (5 M/dk)